# Is there a way to Package up ALL components of an App in the same directory (including images, HTML, CSS, & JS)?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am wondering is there a way for me to package up all the contents of an app in the same app directory?

I want to have all the HTML, CSS, JS, and Image files associated with my apps in the same directory as the app itself (the views.py).

I then want the views.py to be able to access these files and render them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? I guess you just create static directory there and include path to it in STATICFILES_DIRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See my [example project](https://github.com/radicalbiscuit/django-testallinone) for a simple proof-of-concept.**

Yes, you can add your app folder to [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) and [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_DIRS)  in your project's `settings.py`. You should note that your source code (`views.py`, `models.py`, etc.) will be collected and served as static files as well. This is a *very* **unrecommended** practice.

It may also be possible to write/specify a different [staticfiles finder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS) and [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS) to look in your base app folders so you don't have to specify each app in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

I feel strongly that the convention of `templates` and `static` subdirectories is the best way to go, but I've answered your question and I wash my hands of it.

Comment: Hmmm this is kind of what I was wanting, but I still want to have a seperate staticfiles directory and templates directory...

Comment: Well, you're in luck, because that's the canonical way of doing it in Django. Your question was very specific as to wanting all the static files and templates "in the same directory as the app itself." However, simply create a `templates` subfolder and `static` subfolder inside your app folder. The default Django configuration will find them there.

Comment: I've been away from the country past few days... Holy crap are you serious, I'm going to try this now... Had no idea that this was a possibility!

Comment: Perfect this worked! Thank you very much (I thought I had to have a seperate static and templates directory in the root of the project only haha)